# Is it possible to subscribe on event when backbonejs view is removed from dom?

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to subscribe on event when backbonejs view is removed from dom?

I need to handle this to unsubscribe from websocket connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using Jquery UI. I've described solution in my blog: http://zakharov.posterous.com/how-to-handle-when-backbonejs-view-is-remove

Comment: the link is no longer working, maybe it would have been better if you added an answer instead of just linking to an external resource

Answer (score 0):

What triggers the removal of the view from the DOM?  If the view is managing this removal, whomever created the view or has a reference to the view can register to receive an event that the view can trigger when this DOM removal happens.

I haven't tried it, but you might be able to wire up the DOMNodeRemoved event as an event that the view registers a function for.  You would then bubble this DOM event up through your app for any interested listener to respond to.

Comment: it seems that DOMNodeRemoved is not cross browser event

Comment: Yeah, I would not have used the DOMNodeRemoved event, preferring the first method I describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a custom event on the method which is being called to close down the view. Then just have something listening to this event.

Comment: View is replaced by another view inside parent view using jquery html method.